# Intellij idea indent on wrap

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, indentation

My current formatting makes too much intend when wrapping line in XML file. I get this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

but I want this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

I tried changing continuation indent in `Code Style -> General` and in `Code Style -> XML` but none worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to un-tick the `Align attributes` in order to have continuation indentation to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from just unticking `Align attributes` you also have to set the `Continuation indent` to the desired level.

For me the default value was 8, but to get the desired outcome as per your question I had to set this to 4.

To do this go here:
*IntelliJIdea -> Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> On the tab that is labelled "Tabs and Indents"*